# Textarea re-sizing does not work through HTML or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, textarea

I am having issues with re-sizing my textarea. The cols and rows attributes included in HTML do not seem to be working and when I try to re-size it in CSS through the normal width and height properties, the text is displayed in the middle of the box instead of in the top left:

```
.textarea input {
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
```

[textarea print screen with text displayed in centre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxanS.png)

Comment: what you really want to do?you want to increase size of input texts or sixe of the textarea box

Comment: I want to increase the size of the actual textarea box but when I change the size, the text appears in the centre left of the textarea

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML. It looks from the CSS as though there is some confusion between an HTML textarea and an input.

Answer (score 2):

You are using probably using the input tag. That's not a proper approach to add a full length text area. Try using the textarea tag and adjust the size using rows and columns attribute.

Comment: Up vote because this is the first answer to actually describe the underlying problem and suggest a fix. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 56px;
}
```